# Interface acts as if he was a pointer

Tags: typescript, pointers, interface

I have an interface (A), with an interface inside (B). Interface A is used as an array of interface A.

When I update an interface B in specific interface A, ALL same interface B in any interface A is updated too.

If I use the same method but set an interface A attribute, is correct.

I've made a smart code for example.

We've clients eat some x product by minutes. I need to know how many farms I need to deserve all the client.

Client as a product, eatByMinute, and howMany (howMany Client).
Farm as a product, makeByMinute (HowMany product make by minutes).

I inject "Farm interface" in "Client interface" for getting on the big data object. And I what to calculate "How Many farms I need".

If I set HowManyNeed in "Farm interface", all same "Farm interface" in all "Client interface" take the same value.

If I set HowManyFarmNeed in "Client Interface", each value is correct

Logic is :

Init->Start->CountFarmNeed->end

---

```
    const farms: IFarm[] =
        [{
            "name": "AppleFarm",
            "product": "Apple",
            "makeByMinute": 2
        }, {
            "name": "PerryFarm",
            "product": "Perry",
            "makeByMinute": 1
        }
        ];

    interface IFarm {
        name: string,
        product: string,
        makeByMinute: number,
        howManyNeed?: number
    }

    interface IClient {
        name: string,
        eatByMinute: number,
        whatDoesEat: string,
        howMany: number,
        farm?: IFarm,
        howManyFarmNeed?: number
    }

    export class Client {
        static get(name: string, eatByMinute: number, whatDoesEat: string, howMany: number): IClient {
            return {name: name, 'eatByMinute': eatByMinute, 'whatDoesEat': whatDoesEat, 'howMany': howMany}
        }
    }

    export class Farm {
        static getByProduct(product: string): IFarm {
            //@ts-ignore: array.Find can return "Undefined" BUT function return IFarm. In this exemple is ok
            return farms.find((item: IFarm) => item.product == product);
        }
    }

    export default class Problem {
        static init() {
            let clients: IClient[] = [
                Client.get('men', 0.25, 'Apple', 2000),
                Client.get('women', 0.30, 'Perry', 1500),
                Client.get('dog', 0.25, 'Apple', 3000),
            ];
            clients = this.start(clients);
            clients = this.countFarmNeed(clients);
            this.end(clients)

        }

        static start(clients: IClient[]):IClient[] {
            for (let c in clients) {
                clients[c] = this.loadFarm(clients[c]);
            }
            return clients
        }

        static loadFarm(client: IClient): IClient {
            client.farm = Farm.getByProduct(client.whatDoesEat);
            return client;
        }

        static countFarmNeed(clients: IClient[]):IClient[] {
            for (let c in clients) {
                //@ts-ignore: clients[].farm possibly undifined. In this exemple is ok
                clients[c].farm.howManyNeed = (clients[c].howMany * clients[c].eatByMinute) / clients[c].farm.makeByMinute;
                //@ts-ignore: clients[].farm possibly undifined. In this exemple is ok
                clients[c].howManyFarmNeed = (clients[c].howMany * clients[c].eatByMinute) / clients[c].farm.makeByMinute;
            }
            return clients
        }

        static end(clients:IClient[]){
            console.log(clients)
        }
    }
```

---

I expect

```
[0].farm.howManyNeed:250;
[1].farm.howManyNeed:450;
[2].farm.howManyNeed:375;
```

But actual has:

```
[0].farm.howManyNeed:375;
[1].farm.howManyNeed:450;
[2].farm.howManyNeed:375;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `clients[0].farm` and `clients[2].farm` refer to the same object, so of course they will have the same value `howManyNeed` property.  The `countFarmNeed()` function overwrites any earlier change to `farm.howManyNeed` if a new `client` has the same `farm`.

If you want to have two different objects, you will have to make a *copy* of the `farm` object from the `farms` array instead of just returning it, as in:

```
const Farm = {
  getByProduct(product: string): IFarm {
    // don't use ts-ignore for trivial type checking like this
    const farm = farms.find((item: IFarm) => item.product == product);
    // throw a runtime error if you get a problem, and TS understands tihs
    if (!farm) throw new Error("Failed to find farm for " + product);
    // if you get here, then farm is not undefined
    return Object.assign({}, farm); // copy of the farm
  }
};
```

Here I've used [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the properties from `farm` into a new object before returning it.  Now you will get the results you expect.

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgQwE4FsIC4YEkBiyUDaAujALwwEBQMMA3tTTGAigKaYBEAggA48A2rPKg4AaBjR5IQAEwCuwKJ14DWYiTBQIA1qwBCATwCyASzByo7GACYGAX3E16jJiyscACqyRIDwlOouUrIKSjCe3r6BjFq6hqbmlpgAjPaURADclJRmlkiIwKzY-nQMzGyY0EhmAOZZktLyipVQ1WB1DLH6xmYWVuYoAEbe9TAAFiAA7kYIYAYAcqysMgD8mAPDSFl22bneBUVYAML8JqxgsM6uFTBVtaOsCFDxvUlMckMjDJNjTwAiIFYEAAok8Wm0OjQJtNZgZ1h9NqNEKg1sV8KNoTM5v5FstURsvjtKMB+AgIBAYCczhdSjRoE8TMAYDVWFAABQacpWO7tRyMR7PHqJfoI7x8mg-f6AkFg26tWri8ZTLFw96fJAMACUmGOp3Olw0SFZciQYFpLmu-TcipoApewswdqFfRtMElUABQNBYXdnplUFdmNhmCDcw0dlGOyJoEgsBK5CuLMFHkaoTZwSaYR5NW1aNQ5poAHpCzAZOAAOSwOQQIpQCAAWhMNTAICN8FbMHlADcTAh+J2DDwisAxqxgNpajBTrpO2MTBBFTHoPB8GQV6gIAA6OBmGRstkmSwoHX+TVkAB8MEPrBQm4zoTI5Hvik1oyLJagY2kkxgCBgSDkC4TDYGBIg7Ew4BgAwQDkZlWV-GBgkGQQUFEX8wBkGAABUAGUYEAmRvHpDCKSgEwxggDQIJgNkAEJkRQM9P2-JhWB-YEfFbNkODwExBEwqAQHgXd1xQdskHCGAAGpENTF83xgYsr0g6DYKTcZvFYNDP3OUSrwpFsqww1gdzAZZDWNU0YAAeUGAArMcoE3MkICbMA2VoBxRNfRSS1AHgDBgEBIJ00S0gjbISRcmAUxAZCb3NekyKZMxDzZM8rhoQRYBJak6x1Kl9WINcqAtSk9QuTck24tgwDEGAAAZN2sABWNDuD4QR6usBres1V1Csq6qOEmEBavqpqAGZ2q8HwDHq5IWr6gaKqc4ayxqCbmra8IVC6tDJt6hrNQ0TINFy-UKXIT9503ekkHZC6LggV9ztWq7Z1u0BAKgHElj3J661elwbq3c4Afe4GYCJOkoAZJl7se96CtW4hc11PLisy8SaOymAUrNQGXoLRgiYIYASGuuct34EAEBkfw2TJimoZoHYXCNKATUJ97I2yWH4anOmGfwJnVpRvL0cGg0XEB7dV3IfwqtZQxYszMW8s3X1pW9Vn-0snm8r5hgksZfGYIuP7lg1y6JaKogpdRkhsbgDs2TxwGgsgomMo0Ggl1gBi1zlhiFJoai6IYpivymVj2M4pBuPmISg9diTAY4aT8dWzcuT1mgGM3UMFn+sg-cYG3KuLmAACps81p0Ej6M8S0Lrp7T6MP6-1IvlVhK3MPIQvi9xGQFPZxhOe57vnuNgXktAjDK-y7BpbRkmlxAQRN1pmpl5evmiVi+Lb1S9lXqAA)

Please note that the rest of the code has some troublesome issues that you might want to address:

- Don't use [`// @ts-ignore` comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) to suppress simple type checking errors.  That is overkill and might have strange side effects.  If all you're doing is asserting something isn't `undefined`, you could just use the [non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) or just go ahead and check it for `undefined` at runtime and rely on TypeScript's [control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to eliminate the possibility.
- You seem to be using `class` to contain only `static` methods, which is strange.  You could, instead, just use a plain old object (`class Foo {static bar() {}}` becomes `const Foo = {bar() {}}`) or even a [`namespace` or `module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) if you're just trying to give a name to a group of related things.
- It is [generally discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) to iterate over an array using a `for...in` loop.  Consider a more conventional iteration method such as a[`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).
- Objects with key names are generally easier to understand than a list of parameters.  Your `Client.get(a,b,c,d)` method is significantly more confusing than just using object literals like `{ name: a, eatByMinute: b, whatDoesEat: c, howMany: d }`.  In the former the developer needs to remember the order of the parameters, and not to pass `whatDoesEat` in for `name` (they are both `string`s).  In the latter there is no order to worry about.

I'll stop there for now.  Hope that is of some help to you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you for all this advise ! I learn typescript :) if it can reassure you,, i never use @ts-ignore in my code. If my IDE say i've make a mistake .. I belive him  ^^' 

Thank you a lot !